# Indicate that R package is proprietary

Tags: r, r-package

Is there a standard way how to indicate that R package is proprietary, owned by a company and should not be shared outside of the company? Right now, I am using this in `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
License: Proprietary, ownership of XX Company
```

Comment: Seems more like documenting it rather than a legal matter.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you're right actually. Retracting close vote :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the License: field of the DESCRIPTION file and the LICENSE file for the actual license.  For more info see: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Licensing